# iframe src in Haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I always get an empty page when using an iframe. I put, in *src*, the location of the Haml file containing the code to create the checkboxes:

view.haml:

```
%iframe{:src => "file:///home/marina/project/app/views/blog_posts/new2.haml"}
```

new2.haml:

```
%h1 popup
br
%input{:name => "option1", :type => "checkbox", :value => "Milk"}
Milk
%br
%input{:name => "option2", :type => "checkbox", :value => "Butter"}
Butter
%br
%input{:name => "option3", :type => "checkbox", :value => "Cheese"}
Cheese
%br
```

Answer (score 5):

Try :

If files on same place

```
%iframe{:src => "blog_posts/new2.haml"}
```

else suggest to use it as :

make a routes for new2 action and call into iframe via url like  :

```
%iframe{:src => "http://yourdomain.com/new2"}
```

Comment: @Viki, it gave me this error, BSON::InvalidObjectId in BlogPostsController#show

illegal ObjectId format: new2

Comment: u mean i should make an action in the controller? and what do you mean by mydomain.com?

Comment: i'm sorry i'm just a biginner and i'm not quite good in it :D

Comment: Sorry ... the day was off for me :) .

Comment: Marina ... its quite simple to make routes . 1) just take a look on http://railscasts.com/episodes/203-routing-in-rails-3 and make it like match "/new2" => "blog_posts#new2" . 2) Add action def new2 end into your blog_posts controller  3) yourdomain.com means run it like "http://localhost:3000/new2"